# Insert content in the middle of a Django template variable

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have an **Article** model in Django. I am pulling a few paragraphs for each article from the database as shown below (there is a Markdown custom template tag):

```
{{ article.text|markdownify|safe }}
```

Which gives me something like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.</p>
<p>Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur.</p>
<p>Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus.</p>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to insert something in between those paragraphs, perhaps another Django variable containing other information from the database or some more complicated logic (if statements etc). It will be a set of images in my case.

I am aiming for something like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.</p>
<p>Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur.</p>

{% if 1==1 %}
  {{ article.more_stuff }}
{% endif %}

<p>Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus.</p>
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this through a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).  Something like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_article(context, article):
    t = template.Template(article.text)
    return t.render(context)
```

Then in your templates:

```
{% render_article article %}
```

Docs about rendering a string as a template are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system).  Just be *very* careful about allowing untrusted users to create articles.  Someone could put `{{ article.__class__.objects.all.delete }}` in an article text, causing every article to get deleted when that is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any built in way to do this. You could implement something yourself, perhaps in the form of a template tag that parses the content with BeautifulSoupv and breaks it up into a list of paragraphs, then assigns that list to a variable you can iterate through.